# Optimisation when there are ties: Along with other constraints

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have managed to build an Optimisation model(minimize) using glpk plugin in R it works fine when there are no ties in my cost matrix. However, in my real data set, I have ties within my cost matrix and I would like to apply a condition/constraint in that case. So, the constraint I would like to apply is if there is a tie within the cost matrix pick the provider where quality is high for that product. I would be grateful if anyone could point me how to approach this scenario. here is the link to the code i have written so far

here is the script I have 
https://github.com/karthikkommalapati/optimization_contract_bidding_allocation/blob/master/functions.R

So, let us say if the cost/score is the same use the maximum score matrix to and whoever has​ the maximum score wins the lot.

Comment: Haven´t checked your case but if you are minimizing cost and if same cost want best quality, a common way is minimize cost * q - quality, choosing q such that function would still prefer lowering cost than staying with higher cost but better quality. Another way is once you know the minimum cost, solve another model where you want to maximize quality with the constrain that cost = what you got earlier

Comment: Hi Juvian, thank you for your reply. Please, could you point me to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is as follows:

1. Solve problem with min cost objective. Assume this has a cost CBEST
2. Add a constraint to the problem: total cost = CBEST
3. Solve problem with max quality objective.

When implementing this, I usually add both objectives to the model (as constraints). So the first model becomes:

```
  min cost
  cost = cost equation
  quality  = quality equation
  other constraints
```

Solve this model and record the objective as CBEST. Now fix the variable cost to CBEST (e.g. by setting the upperbound of cost to CBEST). Now solve:

```
  max quality
  cost = cost equation
  quality  = quality equation
  other constraints
  cost <= CBEST
```

Note that we only changed two things: (1) the objective and (2) a bound on cost.

The solution of the second model gives what you want.

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thanks for getting back, I am not sure how I can use your approach in this case. Are you suggesting that I solve first by finding the minimum cost and use the output as an input to the next model to find the max quality? I do not think it will work though if you think it does please could you point out to me an example?  In my scenario all I wanted to do is if there is a tie across a product i.e. cost from two suppliers is same then use quality as a tie-breaker to find which supplier has the best quality product.

Comment: It will work, just might take more time as you are solving 2 things. My other solution can be faster in some cases but this one is the more general working and easiest to implement one, so you should try it. As for "all you wanted", there is not even a way to know if there is a tie without doing this.

Comment: This is a fairly standard lexicographic approach in multi-objective optimization. There must be thousands of references.

Comment: Hi Erwin, I am not sure if I follow your response. I don't think  I can use quality constraint in model 1 as I only need to look at that option if there is a tie? Also, In R how can I record the objective in a variable? Sorry, I am new to programming unless I see an exmaple I dont get things around.

Comment: I believe my answer is both correct and detailed enough so it can be implemented in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin, finally managed to do it myself, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Very good. You should see that `cost` is the same in both models and that `quality` may improve.